# Cucumber : Integration with two different projects

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumber, bdd

We have two different projects, one in JS and the other with Java, you know if a single cucumber layer can help me integrate between two project, let's say that one project (JS) is running some operations (testing) that appear on the web application and the second project (JAVA) is running the actions on a mobile device, so we want to be able to combine the two actions, mobile and web application, appreciate the help or ideas, thanks Eyal

Comment: one more comment, I meant to install Cucmber on both projects , then to reuse each these 2 project's actions

Answer (score 0):

1) Are they different projects or the same project but there are 2 or 3 out of web, ios or android versions?

2) Must you write your automation suite in the same language as the application to install test data or use it on this suite?

If you answered 1) with "different projects" or 2) with "Yes" - then it's not wise to do this.

If you want to write a library of helper functions for cross platform purposes, then you can definitely do that. I'm currently looking into the 3 platforms myself, dividing my library into modules and requiring the one I need at the start of run time.

**EDIT**

In your case, I would go for writing a Cucumber JVM framework, as Java has more robust libraries for working with Desktop and Android applications than JS, from what I've seen on this site.

Comment: Hi Kyle Thanks for your comments, it is not my choice , its a fact that we have several teams each of team write code in different style as i wrote, the only question is about Cucumber, if support working with two different projects

Comment: You should never put features of a different project within the features of another. The feature files are basically the business specifications for what the functionality should be in a project. Merging two projects merges two specifications.

Comment: Thanks Kyle agree with you :)